# Is this a bug of lex?

Tags: lex

rule:

```
%%
AAAA     print("AAAA     : %s\n",yytext);
AAA     print("AAA     : %s\n",yytext);
AA     print("AA     : %s\n",yytext);
```

And the input is `AAAAA`,the output is:

```
AAAA     : AAAA
A
```

Instead of :

```
AAA     : AAA
AA      : AAA
```

Is it a bug of lex?

Comment: "A bug of lex" could mean "a bug of you". ;]

Comment: That's fine as long as you provide a reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's adhering to the specification.

The rule is ([man 1p lex](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/lex))

> During pattern matching, lex shall search the set of patterns for the single longest possible match. Among rules that match the same number of characters, the rule given first shall be chosen.

so it will always greedily search for the longest `AAAA` first. This rule is common in lexical conventions of many languages. Eg. C++:

```
void f(void*=0);
```

would fail to parse, because the characters `*=` are interpreted as assign-multiplication operator (which is the longest match), not `*` and then `=`.

The reason behind this rule is it can be implemented efficiently. The scanner with this rule only needs O(1) space (including input, ie. input need not fit into memory) and O(N) time. If it were to check that the rest of the input can be tokenized as well, it would need O(N) space and as much as O(N^2) time. Particularly the memory consumption was crucial in the Middle Ages of computing when all compilation was done in linear passes. And I'm sure you wouldn't appreciate O(N^2) running time when parsing today's several-hundred-thousand line source files (eg. C files including headers). Second, the scanners thus generated are very fast and help a lot when parsing.

Last, but not least, the rule is simple to understand. As an example of the opposite, consider ANTLR's rule for tokenization, which would sometimes fail to match even though a prefix of the current token is a token, and the input minus that prefix is tokenizable. For example:

```
TOK1 : 12
TOK2 : (13)+
```

would fail to match '12131312'. No such surprises happen with lex; so I suggest to take the rule as-is.

Comment: Why it doesn't regard whether all parts can be matched at all?

Comment: @lex: Short answer - because that's not what a lexer is for, it's up to you to design the language in such a way that it matches right. The longer answer is that it in general would be massively inefficient, and require a lot of processing, to figure out whether there is a way to match all the tokens, because this is a bit like a difficult jigsaw puzzle, and is very similar to solving the NP-complete subset-sum problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @psmears: It's not NP-hard, nor similar. Still, it would be grossly inefficient. See my updated answer.

Comment: It *is* similar, in the sense that in both problems you are trying to put together a number of smaller objects (integers, tokens) to match a larger object (sum, text to parse). The difference is that simpler statements of the lex problem are more amenable to dynamic-programming type approaches. However, lex itself is not as simple as you make out, and it is certainly *not* O(1) in space - because the tokens can be arbitrary regular expressions, so `a.*b` is a valid token (which could match the entire input) - and remember that the output of the lexer contains the matched token!